# Search for problem connectin samsung gt s5570 to pc

Tags: android

I am having samsung gt s5570 mobile, when i load videos from my PC through localhost. The videos are not playing. But when i tried to play same video through SD card, its playing... can anyone suggest how to rectify this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a streaming server for that... According to my guess u need a server and client for this.. You cannot play on the go.. also do check for the format of video.

Comment: Yeah you are rite, i used to play with localhost, even i gave my Ip number along with port id.and i used 3gp video file. its is not working. Is that any security setting to change for enable this video files..???

Comment: I am not sure about the security settings.. But you can search the market for free video streaming apps. Some paid versions are also there.

Comment: I use VLC Direct and doubleTwist AirSync. You could try them too. I love VLC because it supports two-way streaming.

Comment: okay, actually the problem is, i created multimedia application, and i access video file from PC through local host. This application is successfully running in Emulator and HTC mobiles but same apk when i installed in samsung gt s5570, its not working. whenever i tried to play video nothing will displayed. No sound no video. I used sdk version of 2.2